# Malformed Line 61 (dist parse)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I run `sudo apt-get update` but it returns:

```
E: Malformed line 61 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I opened the sources.list via `vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

and Line 61 is : `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/precise-pgdg main`

I am not sure what is malformed about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space after `apt/`:

```
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg
```